# Clarification about combinations and permutation problems.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have a problem, 50 people consisting of 25 boys and 25 girls are going to send 20 people to a conference. How many ways can you select 20 people so that there are 10 girls and 10 boys?

This is where I get confused with these types of problems. I believe it would be a combination problem cause order doesn't matter in this case. (could be wrong about that) Also, would I set it up as 50C10 multiplied by 50C10? By 50C10 I mean the formula for combinations of nCk, where I am choosing 10 from a set of 50. Maybe I am just overthinking the problem cause I am new to the concept but some help would be appreciated. Am I correct, or way off?

Comment: You're not choosing anybody from the group of 50.  You're only selecting boys, then girls.  So you selecting 10 boys from 25 boys total.

Comment: you are close. but what does 50 choose 10 mean?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that it's a combination since order doesn't matter. But remember you're choosing $10$ girls/boys from $25$ and not from $50$. So it's ${25\choose 10}{25\choose 10}.$

Answer (score 1):

First choose the $10$ boys out of the $25$ boys to be in the conference. Then choose the $10$ girls out of the $25$ girls to be in the conference. These are independent choices. Hence there are
$$
\binom{25}{10}\binom{25}{10}
$$
ways.

Comment: I think I understand now. So you would calculate the odds of 10 boys being chosen from 25 boys, and 10 girls being chosen from 25 girls, and then multiply the 2 results for your final answer? I think that makes sense, but it just bothers me how we are basically separating the 50 person group into subgroups, and then calculating it that way. How does that not interfere with the problem?

Comment: We can do the division in this case because the collections of boys and girls exhaust the 50 people and the collections are disjoint.

Comment: @Conner You aren't calculating the odds of anything. You're calculating the number of possible ways to choose 10 boys from the 25 boys. You aren't choosing from 50 boys. (I suppose you are choosing them from 50 people, but the girls are irrelevant to the choice of the 10 boys since you can't choose them.) Then you can pair up any choice of 10 boys with any choice of 10 girls to get a set of 20 for the conference, so you multiply.